# the difference between "inherit from a class" and "having a member is the class itself"

Tags: c++

What is the differences between these two child classes generally, and specifically in relation to memory:
(1)

```
class parent{};
class child : parent{};
```

(2)

```
class parent{};
class child{
  parent parent_object;
};
```

Is that true that whatever functionality we can achieve with (1) we can achieve with (2) too?

Comment: Related: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: In C++ the principal difference is that the first option enables an automatic conversion from `Child*` to `Parent*`. Whether that means you achieve the same functionality or not is a matter of what precisely you mean by 'functionality'.

Comment: @john Except OP uses private inheritance (whether intentionally or not) and so it won't be implicit. The conversion will only happen if a C-style cast is used.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I was just going to modify my comment. I suspect this is just a poorly phrased question.

Comment: @OP: What kind of functionality are you asking about? What potential memory problem do you see? Your question seems way to general: Obviously the two are not identical in all respects. That already starts at the theoretical level of inheritance vs composition in object oriented programming theory. Is that what you are interested in or something C++-specific or something about some compiler's/platforms specific class layout decision in memory, etc.?

Comment: @user17732522 , I'm currently working on game development (as a beginner). So I guess functionalities I want to know is like like "C++ functions" ( attack(), kill() ... ) and so on :)

Comment: @Crackie I suggest to ask about that specific class you have in mind then. Whether one should use composition or inheritance is mainly a matter of what, abstractly, the classes represent, i.e. whether there is a "is-a"-relation between the things the classes represent. It is unlikely that some C++-specific details will matter to you, although you should generally know about `virtual` functions to use inheritance correctly in the sense of object oriented programming theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions can achieve similar functionality in terms of having a relationship between the `parent` and `child` classes, they represent different concepts in OOPs.

Inheritance `class child: parent{};` represents an "is-a" relationship, where `child` is a specialized version of `parent`.
Composition `class child {parent parent_obj;};` represents "has-a" relationship, where `child` has a `parent` object as a member.

Comment: the first concept is inheritance and second is Composition

Answer (score 1):

In the former case, child inherits the members of parent. In the latter case, parent becomes a member of child. It is true that you can achieve the same functionality both ways, but you will lose the ability to occlude parent members with overriden versions in the child class if you do not use inheritance. On the other hand, you will gain a lot of flexibility.

In general, if child is a customized/specific version of parent, I would inherit. If child needs only a part of parent, then make parent a member.